# How to load your own labels for the classifier

Tags: python, label, image-classification

I am a newbie here. I have a file path that lists all the images but I am stuck with connecting the labels to the images. I have a CSV file that has image no and the label. What would be the best way to approach this issue? FYI I am using a pre-trained model (Python).

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @7006. I suspect you'll need to provide more details, such as snippets of code, what you've tried, specific error messages, etc., to get useful feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to create a numpy array of images with labels as a dimension? You can use the following code:

```
def class_segmentation(dir_path,df):
    
    """ takes a given folder and splits it into respective classes based on the csv file labels
    mapped to the names of the files
    dir_path = path of the directory which needs to be segmented
    classes = list of classes present in the dataset, as string
    
    """
    image_list = os.listdir(dir_path)
    classes = get_classes(df)
    
    for clas in classes:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path,clas))
    
    for image in image_list:
        if(image in df['image_extensions'].tolist()):
            label = (df[df['image_extensions']==image]['label']).tolist()[0]
            image_path_src = os.path.join(dir_path, image)
            dest = os.path.join(dir_path, str(label))
            image_path_dest = os.path.join(dest,image)
            shutil.move(image_path_src, image_path_dest)
```

Next you need to convert these images to numpy array, and load the corresponding labels.

```
def img_to_array_data(dir_path, classes):
    data_array = []
    for clas in classes:
        classpath = os.path.join(dir_path,str(clas))
        for img in os.listdir(classpath):
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(classpath,img))
            data_array.append([img_array,clas])
            
    random.shuffle(data_array)    
    
    X =[]
    y =[]

    for features, label in data_array:
        X.append(features)
        y.append(label)
        
    X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, dim[0], dim[0], 3)
    X = X.astype('float32')
    X /= 255
    
    Y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, 5)
    
    return X,Y
```

Of course, don't forget to import all the necessary libraries: `os`, `np_utils` etc.